# Can't access checkboxes after clearing panel jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, devexpress

I have a panel named pBody with some textboxes and checkboxes and radio buttons and a button (all by devExpress).
I want to clear form by clicking Clear button and check some checkboxes. The clearing is Ok but after that I cant access checkboxes by their ID and ClientInstanceName.

```
function ClearForm() {
    $("#pBody input[type=text]").val('');
    var status = document.getElementById("CB1").checked;
            if (status)
                alert('Checked!');
            else
                alert('UnChecked!');
}
```

I always get unchecked message. So I can't do what I want. I have this problem with Radio buttons, too.

```
<dx:ASPxCheckBox ClientInstanceName="CB_Amoozeshi" CssClass="btnInline" ID="CB1" runat="server" Text="Checkbox1" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [ClientInstanceName](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxEditorsASPxEditBase_ClientInstanceNametopic) of the ASPxCheckBox control is specified as "`CB_Amoozeshi`" and you can directly set or access values of DevExpress controls client side. Use `ClientInstanceName` and get the state of ASPxCheckBox using the [GetChecked](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxEditorsScriptsASPxClientCheckBox_GetCheckedtopic) Method . So you snippet should be as like:

```
function ClearForm() {
    $("#pBody input[type=text]").val('');
    var status = CB_Amoozeshi.GetChecked(); /// this is the change you need to check
            if (status)
                alert('Checked!');
            else
                alert('UnChecked!');
}
```

Reference:
[ASPxCheckBox - How to get the checkbox state via client-side API](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q356202)
[How to check / uncheck ASPxCheckBox on the client side](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q293700)
[ASPxCheckBox - SetChecked method issue](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q292656)

Comment: @Behnam8: Great.. Then always remember to accept answer that resolved your issue. Refer: [How to update and accept answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251078/how-to-update-and-accept-answers)